# Linux installation to LiveCD?

Tags: livecd

I currently have a few VM images of both Debian and Ubuntu. I was thinking it might be nice to burn them as a live CD on DVD-media and carry it around with me in case I need it whatever reason.

Is it possible to take my current Linux installation and burn it as a LiveCD or USB? The problem I thought I may have is the fact its on read only media. I'm using Debian and I may want to do this with Ubuntu as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Ubuntu you have **Remastersys**. To install it use the following command

sudo apt-get install remastersys

To make a distributable livecd/dvd of your system use command

sudo remastersys dist
this will create iso image in /home/remastersys/ folder. Then burn it! :)
**LINK** http://www.ubuntugeek.com/creating-custom-ubuntu-live-cd-with-remastersys.html